# Async init on i18next reload resurce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, i18next

I'm using the i18next library in version `"i18next": "^21.8.0"` ,to localize my React app.

When I tried to reload an await resource, I saw many examples, but no one was able to show me how to load a json file async.

When I try to add the resource through `console.log(await langRequest)`, I get the correct input.

There is the function that returns the JSON file correctly for me:

```
const langRequest = async () => {
    const url = createUrl('Ajax/GetStrings', { lang: 'he' });
    const languageResponse = await get(url);
    return languageResponse;
}
```

And there is the init method:

```
i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    resources: {
        he: { translation: await langRequest }
    },
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    react: {
        useSuspense: false
    }
})
```

I tried to write this code witout `await` before the `langRequest` but it still not working.

- The init is outside of component brackets.
- I tried using an empty resource and `i18next.addResourceBundle(language, {languageResponse});`
  in useEffect, but got the following error:

> bundle.js:149045 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: key.indexOf is not a
> function
> at cleanKey (bundle.js:149045:23)
> at getLastOfPath (bundle.js:149069:8)
> at getPath (bundle.js:149092:25)
> at ResourceStore.addResourceBundle (bundle.js:149411:18)
> at I18n._this2. [as addResourceBundle] (bundle.js:151544:50)
> at bundle.js:868:53

Thanks a lot to all helpers!

Answer (score 0):

Loading resources via http does not work like that...
You need an i18next backend plugin.

A complete blog post based on react can be found [here](https://locize.com/blog/how-to-internationalize-react-i18next/#separate).

Also have a look at [this documentation](https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations#add-after-init).